# Refer to ComboBox that is just created after user input

Tags: excel, vba, userform

i am trying to have VBA create a user form and based off of what selection you choose populate more selections.

the following code is my initial user form and i have it adding Comboboxes Based on whatever selection is chosen.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   ComboBox1.AddItem "Selection1"
   ComboBox1.AddItem "Selection2"
   ComboBox1.AddItem "Selection3"
   ComboBox1.FontSize = 13
End Sub
```

But i have it going to comboboxchange to do so

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

'Here i have some Working Code That Adds another ComboBox
Dim MsgType As Control

Set MsgType = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
With MsgType
.Height = 25
.Width = 300
.Top = 75
.Left = 20
.FontSize = 13
.Name = "vmtype"
.AddItem "Selection1"
.AddItem "Selection2"

Debug.Print .Value
End With

EndSub
```

I now need to have a private sub refer to this combo box just as "Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()" had. that way i can add more items depending on that selection.

What i have so far is the following.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

 Dim Notetype As String
 Notetype = ComboBox1.Value
 Debug.Print Notetype

End Sub
```

But it is not actually refering to the newly created Combo Box any idea how i can Fix this?

Comment: I just also thought it may be possible to have certain selections unhide any boxes u need and have them already Created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WithEvents` to listen for dynamically added controls.

Here is a simple example where you are just adding a single control:

```
Private WithEvents vmtype As MSForms.ComboBox

Private Sub vmtype_Change()
    Debug.Print MsgType
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Set vmtype = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
    With vmtype
        .Height = 25
        .Width = 300
        .Top = 75
        .Left = 20
        .FontSize = 13
        .Name = "vmtype"
        .AddItem "Selection1"
        .AddItem "Selection2"
    End With

End Sub
```

Consider using a custom class when adding many control.  See my post: [Responding to Events of Dynamically added Controls](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205263/responding-to-events-of-dynamically-added-controls)

Comment: For me this code still only executes until it is done and clicking on the box to change it does not go to the private sub

Comment: @JacobLupton Sorry about that.  I renamed the variable but not the sub.  I edited my post.